Pinout for Onsemi AR1335 (63-ODCSP/63-WFBGA/CSPBGA)
I am currently working on a project utilizing the Onsemi AR1335 (AR1335CSSC11SMKA0-CP) CMOS Image Sensor, 13 MP, 1/3".
I chose this sensor since my MPU/APU platform (NXP i.MX8M P) already offers drivers and config files for it and it as a solderable packaging instead of the usual wire-bonding.
However - I have problems finding the pinout for the BGA footprint (63-ODCSP/63-WFBGA/CSPBGA) in the datasheets available. Even when contacting Onsemi via contact-form or e-mail directly, I do not get an answer - not even a usual "e-mail received"-Message.
I spent days researching and even found some (ironically) confidential documents with much more critical information on the sensor, that do belong behind a paywall, customer-account or NDA (e.g. die-pinout & pad positions for wire-bonding, register mapping + usage, etc...).
But why would any manufacturer "hide" the sensor-pinout from potential customers, effectively limiting their development? Pinouts are not sensitive information anyways...
Does anyone have the pinout (or a source) available? I am thankful for any sort of advice.
